# How to get projected property in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Let's say I am using NHibernate and want to find some aggregate values of a set. I have something like this:

```
var crit = session.CreateCriteria<T>();
crit.Add(someRestrictions);
crit.SetProjection(
    Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Min(propertyName), "min" + propertyName)
        .Add(Projections.Max(propertyName), "max" + propertyName)
);
var ur = crit.UniqueResult();
var min = ???
var max = ???
```

How do I get the value for `min` and `max`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to create some DTO:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public virtual int MinProperty { get; set; }
    public virtual int MaxProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And this could be the resulting query:

```
var result = crit.SetProjection(
    Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Min(propertyName), "MinProperty") // "min" + propertyName)
        .Add(Projections.Max(propertyName), "MaxProperty") // "max" + propertyName)
    )
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<MyDto>())
    .UniqueResult<MyDto>();
```

Which will return a `MyDto` with typed access to min and max properties